# How to connect to non-local MS SQL Server from WSL2 using Python and Windows Authentication?

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, kerberos

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server which is not running on my local machine.
I'm using a python script developed on WSL2 with pyodbc, but I need to sign into the SQL server with Windows Authentication.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to configure Kerboros inside the WSL2 container. How to set that up, however, isn't a subject for [so].

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication means either NTLM or Kerberos.  NTLM is not available for ODBC on Linux, so you must use [Kerberos on MacOS or Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/using-integrated-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16).